# Cycles is texture stretching and not applying scale correctly

Tags: texturing, materials, uv, node-editor

I've been wrestling with this for hours now, so I've finally succumbed to posting for help.
What I'm trying to do seems simple enough - I want to create a texture that I can use in various different geometries in my scene with a consistent scale, rotation, location etc.
I've searched all the avenues I can think of for similar posts, but nothing seems to solve my problem.
I'll illustrate it below.

[image: FIG 1]

[image: FIG 2]

[image: FIG 3]

So it was suggested on one post I read to use the mapping coordinates node, but I've played around with it in multiple different ways, and it doesn't seem to achieve what I'm after, and I believe it is actually a problem with the geometry, as I will illustrate below.

I created a few different cubes, and have applied smart-uv's, and applied scale, loc and rot to them in various intervals to show what I think the problem is.

[image: FIG 4]

[image: FIG 5]

As you can see from the images above, applying scale etc doesn't seem to effect the size of the texture EVEN after resetting and redoing the smart-uv's.

The following few images just show what the result of changing the mapping vector is (Edit: I couldn't attach all of them sadly, but I did try almost all the options available on blender). Again no success. 
I've also tried changing the image texture from 'flat' to 'box' - again to no avail.

[image: FIG 8]

Any help would be massively appreciated. I'm hoping that I've just missed something obvious!

Many thanks in advance,

Chester

EDIT: 
Here is how it looks with the texture coordinates and mapping node. All the objects that it is applied to have had their scales etc applied and all UV maps deleted.

[image: Mappingnodes2]

[image: 1]

I've created another scene, with a new material and the problem is the same. Very odd.

Comment: I might be misunderstanding your question, but you just need to UV unwrap all your objects, but because the floor is longer than the wall it will show up different on the UV grid, So you need to manually go into each objects UV map and scale it to your desired size.

Comment: You need to apply the scale in Object Mode. Then after UV Unwrapping and with the "Mesh" selected adjust the "scale" of the UV Map(s).

Comment: @icYou520 Ah yes I've taken a look at the UV's and it seems to make sense in terms of why the scale is different. Perhaps UV mapping is the wrong approach for what I'm trying to do then, because what I'm after is a material with a repeating texture that will apply itself with exactly the same scale/ proportions to different objects in the scene, such as in keyshot or modo, where you can apply materials that map themselves (is that box mapping?) without the need for UV's.

Comment: @Dontwalk Thanks - as I've just written above to icYou520, perhaps I'm approaching this in the wrong way by using UV's, as that seems like a very drawn out process to resize and rescale for every bit of geometry, particuarly for something like bricks, where the scale needs to be fairly accurate.

Comment: Sounds like you need the texture coordinates node connected into your mapping node. Use "Generated" or "object" and you will need to change your image textures to box and not flat.

Comment: Change your Mapping node to POINT or VECTOR

Answer (score 2):

Try connecting your texture coordinates node to the mapping node like below. Then you dont need to worry about UV's at all.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your continued help, but sadly it still isn't working. I've posted an image of how it's come out as an EDIT in the original post. All the geometry you can see has exactly the same material applied, and I have applied the scale etc to all of them. Weirdly the material is coming up fine in the preview to the right, but seems to be glitching and doing all sorts of weird things on the actual model. Any ideas?

Comment: If the objects are all seperate you will need to adjust the scale on the mapping node of all objects with the brick texture. If you join (CTRL+J) all the objects as one then the texture will be the same scale for everything.